# How to find the parent keys of a jsonpath result

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression, jsonpath-ng

I have this json obj

```
{
  "abc": {
    "some_field": {
      "title": "Token",
      "type": "password"
    },
    "some_field_2": {
      "title": "Domain",
      "type": "text"
    },
    "some_field_3": {
      "title": "token2",
      "type": "password"
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to get a list of keys `[some_field,some_field_3]` where `type=password`

This jsonpath `$..[?(@.type=='password')]` returns:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Token",
    "type": "password"
  },
  {
    "title": "token2",
    "type": "password"
  },
]
```

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, just need to add a `~` to the end to get the key(s) instead of the value(s):

```
$..[?(@.type=='password')]~
```

Note: this might not work depending on your jsonpath engine. It works on https://jsonpath.com.